# Battery drains on my LG G3 despite everyone saying it has a great battery life

Tags: battery-life, lg-g3

So I have my LG G3 for 5 days and the battery life is not what i expected. I am not a real havy user, when I am home WiFi is turned on when I'm using the internet, data is always turned off like bluetooth and NFC. Brightness is at 20-30% with autobrightness turned off.
Some people say that it needs time to get the battery life to be stable but I don't know how long I have to wait...
Can someone please explain to me what is happening. Should I change the battery or is this everything normal ?

P.S. My last phone was a Galaxy Mini S5570, maybe I am not used to this kind of battery ?

Comment: What's the screen on time that you're achieving?

Comment: After 2 weeks it has goten better. Now I have 13% remaining with a little bit more than 4h of SoT.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a longshot for you, but i changed the home launcher on my g3 to google now launcher from playstore and battery improved a lot.

Comment: LG's launcher is known to be a ressource hog, so this might indeed help.